# Prove that the set of all functions which remain constant over intervals is a subspace, with dimension 5

Tags: functions, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I am having trouble with the following question from my course book:

> Let $V$ be the vector space of all real-valued functions on the interval $[0, 5]$. Prove that the
> set $W$ of all functions $f(x)$ from $V$, which are constant on each of the following five intervals: $[0, 1), [1, 2), [2, 3), [3, 4), [4, 5]$ is a subspace in $V$ and $dim W = 5$.

**Proof that $W$ is a subspace:**

Clearly $\mathbb{0} \in W$ as $f(x) = 0$ is constant over all 5 intervals.

Let $f, g \in W$
Clearly $(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ is constant (Do I need to prove this?). Thus $W$ is closed under addition.

Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$
Clearly $(cf)(x) = c(f(x))$ is constant (Again, does this need proof?). Thus $W$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

It follows that $W$ is a subspace of $V$.

**Proof that $dimW = 5$:**

Let $w = \begin{bmatrix}w_1\\w_2\\w_3\\w_4\\w_5\end{bmatrix}$ where $w_i = f(x)$ on interval $[i-1, i)$

With $w \in W$, clearly a basis for $W$ will contain 5 vectors, and thus the dimension of $W = 5$

Comment: For the proof that $\dim W=5$, you want to write out a basis of $W$ say $e_1,...,e_n$ where $e_i$ is the function which is $1$ on the interval $[i-1,i)$ and $0$ else where, and then you need to show that this is a basis (i.e. linearly independent, and spanning W), and that will give you that the dimension of $W$ is $5$

Comment: I would rewrite the last point and consider the homomorphism $V\to \Bbb R^5$, $f\mapsto (f(0),f(1),…,f(4))$ and show that it’s restriction to $W$ is injective and surjective.

Comment: Actually, you can consider the map $V\to V$ that sends $f$ to $x\mapsto f(x)-f(\min\{\lfloor x\rfloor,4\})$, show this is linear, and then $W$ is the kernel …